# Python - write txt file with a list

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a test.txt that contains:

```
-
anything1
go
-
anything2
go
```

And i wanna replace the '-' with my list and some query. Here is my code:

```
x = ['1', '2']
i=0
with open("test.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('-','\nuse '+(str(x[i]))+'\ngo\n'))
            i+=i
```

But my result is:

```
use 1
go
anything1 
go

use 1
go
anything2 
go
```

I need that the second 'use' be 'use 2' and not 'use 1'.

How I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Consider what `i+=i` does when `i` is zero. (posting this as a comment and not an answer because fixing this typo won't completely solve your problem)

Comment: You need some way to tell your replacing script that the n'th occurrence of "-" translates to the n-1 index in x and just replace the occurrence with the value it finds on x[n-1]. A simple counter should do if you match occurrences to list indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
i = (x for x in ['1', '2'])

with open("test.txt") as fin, open("result.txt", "w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('-'):
            fout.write(line.replace('-', '\nuse {}\ngo\n'.format(next(i))))
        else:
            fout.write(line)
```

Comment: I think it would be best to do fout.write(line.replace('-', '\nuse {}\ngo\n'.format(str(x[i-1])))), he may want the value from x.

Comment: You can open the files with one `with` block: `with open("test.txt", "r") as fin,  open("result.txt", "w") as fout:`

Comment: Like it better now?

Comment: I'd use `f'\nuse {next(i)}\ngo\n'` as this super fancy feature of Python 3.6 makes code more beautiful (IMO), but your solution works with every version of modern Python, so it's probably better. But I think that it's worth to say, that both original code and yours would throw some exceptions in case if count of '-' characters in file and your generator/list would have different length (there would be more '-' chars than items in generator).

Comment: @erhesto `next()` also takes default arguments. So one could write `next(i, 'NaN')` for example for bulletproofing. As long as there are `i`s you would get those and when you run out, it will just give `'NaN'`

Comment: Thanks! I just add the part of BoboDarph, it was exactly what i want.