# Why is getting this list index out of range?

Tags: python, list, index-error

I have a 'test.txt' file like example that contains:

```
 --
a
 --
b
 --
c
```

and my Python code:

```
x = ['a','b','c']
i=1
with open("test.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("result.log", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith(' --'):
                fout.write(line.replace(' --','use {}'.format(str(x[i-1]))))
                i+=i
            else:
                fout.write(line)
```

But the result is:

```
fout.write(line.replace(' --','use {}'.format(str(x[i-1]))))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Should be working ... anyone can help me? I'd like to have the result:

```
use a
a
use b
b
use c
c
```

Comment: Presumably because `(i - 1) >= len(x)`. Given that you don't ever check whether or not that's true *before* trying to use the index, it's not clear why this is surprising. Also `i += i` seems a little suspicious. Have you tried any debugging?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, it is right, i was not getting attention on this...

Comment: I forgot to comment on your last question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814761/python-write-txt-file-with-a-list): the way your implementation was building the index was incorrect and you would not be able to match your list properly (resulting in an Index out of bounds error). The accepted answer should also fix that problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

In Python Increment Operator is  look like this `i+=1` But You try to use `i+=i` it always increment i=i+i

> when i=1 then after increment i=2
>
> when i=2 then after increment i=4

You have three element in array so it gives error index out of rage.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `i` with 0 and then in the loop increment it by 1. Also, you don't have to call `str()` because `format()` does it for you. Try this:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
i = 0

with open("test.txt", "r") as fin, open("result.log", "w") as fout:    
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith(' --'):
            fout.write(line.replace(' --','use {}'.format(x[i])))
            i += 1
        else:
            fout.write(line)
```

Output written to `result.log`:

```
use a
a
use b
b
use c
c
```

Answer (score 0):

`i+=i` is causing the exception. you can use:

```
i = 0
// code goes here
i += 1
```